# UIButton with background image highlighted state wrong

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uibutton

I'm trying to use the standard highlighting logic for a UIButton but set the background image for the Normal state.  When do this programmatically everything works fine, but when my button is set in Interface Builder I get the following results:

[image: Normal State]

[image: Highlighted State]

Has anyone run in this where the standard highlighting is changing the way the background image looks?  Just to be clear I want the color change, just not the squared off corners on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Apparently if my button size is smaller than the background image it scales appropriately for Normal State, but the highlighted state causes this strangeness.  Good to know since I'm attempting to use a single image and just scale it for all of my various buttons.

In this case my IB button was set as 77pt wide, but my image is 97pt wide.  It finally looks correct with my IB button set at 90pt wide or larger.